# How binding several ViewModels in MainWindow.xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a MainViewModel and a OtherViewModel in my wpf Mvvm project.
In the MainWindow.Xaml, I set the MainViewModel as the Grid's DataContext. However, I want to set the OhterViewModel as the TextBox control's DataContext, which is in the Grid. How can I implement it? The xaml code as fallows.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Windows1ViewModel" /> 
</Window.Resources>    
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Windows1ViewModel}">
   .....
    <TextBox "require to bind OtherVeiwModel here"/>
   .....
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <Window.Resources>
     <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="Windows1ViewModel" /> 
     <viewModels:OtherViewModel x:Key="OtherViewModel" /> 
  </Window.Resources>    

  <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource Windows1ViewModel}">
     <TextBox DataContext="{StaticResource OtherViewModel}" "require to bind OtherVeiwModel here"/>
  </Grid>
```

Alternately your MainViewModel might be keeping a reference to your OtherViewModel , you can bind the TextBox's DataContext to that alternate view model.

CS:

```
  public class MainViewModel 
  {
       public OtherViewModel OtherViewModel{get {retrurn new OtherViewModel();}}
  }
```

XAML :

```
  <TextBox DataContext="{Binding OtherViewModel, Mode=OneWay}" "require to bind OtherVeiwModel here"/>
```

Comment: Whether I have to instantiate the OtherViewModel in somewhere or not? And if I instantiate the OtherViewModel in the MainWindowViewModel as `otherVM`, can I use the `Window1ViewModel.otherVM` as the TextBox's DataContext?

Comment: I'm not sure , i Think you can try 

DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Window1ViewModel} , Path=OtherViewModel}"